# How to configure Google News to not display murder stories

Tags: google-news

Google News seems to think it needs to show me lots of stories about brutal murders. I don't want to see them. How can I configure Google News so that it doesn't show them?

It would be great to prevent displaying any murder stories, although it would help if I could at least mark individual stories to not be displayed.

I've searched the web but have not been able to figure out how to not display stories or topics. Thank you for any light you can shed on this.

Comment: Navigate to [news.google.com](https://news.google.com) use the search term `"-murder"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but then I get a totally different list of stories -- it's not just the default set without the murder stories.

Answer (score 1):

The "show less stories" button is useless. I've been trying it for months before I had given up. I've even tried completely blocking each and every site that showed this kind of content and I only received more.

The only thing that has worked for me to reduce it but not to completely remove it was a three step process:

1. Inside Google News, keep an eye out for content that I really, really want more of in Google News.
2. When I see an article that I really like, go to the website and see if I consistently want more of that website in Google News.
3. Go to the following section in Google News, search for the brand name or domain (i.e., "nature" or "nature.com" but NOT "https://nature.com"), making sure the site is listed as a source, not as a search result. And click "follow".

This has greatly reduced the percentage of death and murder content that I receive, now if I could only do something about the sports thing which I never watch...

Yes:
[image: Entering "TriplePundit", which shows up as a "source".]
No:
[image: Entering "https://www.triplepundit.com" which will lead to "search results".]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I agree, well said. Try clicking on the 3 dots associated with every murder story that shows up and select, "show me less stories like this one." If you do that enough times it should alter the content feed. It's like weeding your garden.